# Docker could not find plugin bridge in v1 plugin registry: plugin not found

Tags: docker, graphcool

I am trying to run this command with graphcool:

```
graphcool-framework local up
```

And I am getting this error from Docker,

```
docker   could not find plugin bridge in v1 plugin registry: plugin not found
```

My version of Docker is version 18.03.0-ce

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 44):

If you are using Windows; please use 
**docker network create --driver nat network-name**

Answer (score 28):

Are you using Docker for Windows and switched to using Windows containers?

The bridge driver isn't available for Windows containers and nat is the equivalent.

I'm not familiar with graphcool but it could be that its based on a Linux image, that references the bridge driver.

See if graphcool have a windows docker image (one that uses the nat driver instead of bridge).

Comment: Well, when I installed Docker, I selected the Windows containers, not the Linux containers. I am using it on Windows. Can it be because of that? I mean the Windows containers? Should I uninstall it and install again with Linux containers selected?

Comment: That would definitely be worth a go, as long as you have no other containers that need to be on Windows for some reason (ie: DotNetCore).

Comment: switching to Linux containers and now i have this error: "Windows named pipe error: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)". I restart Docker and it works fine!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Docker EE and running Linux containers using LCOW way then you need to create a network using the NAT driver.

The **Bridge Driver is only available on Linux machine** so whenever we use Docker CE (Docker for Windows) and run windows container, Bridge will not work but if we use Linux container Bridge will work smooth and the user will face no issues. Though it's also important to understand that Bridge Driver does not work for Linux containers when we go LCOW way as LCOW internally uses Windows Kernel and Windows kernel has no support for Bridge Driver.

It's important to remember that Docker has made **Bridge as the default Network** Driver so its the responsibility of the person running the container to make a judicious decision about which driver to choose.

Please use the command mentioned below to resolve the error
**`docker network create --driver nat NetworkName`**